# According to Vaishnavism, what is a fruitive activity?

Tags: karma, caste-system, bhakti

I am currently reading Bhakti Rasamrta Sindhu by Rupa Gosvami (with commentary by Jiva Gosvami).

In it, it has been mentioned that a pure devotee is above fruitive activities such as the varnasrama rules and regulations for caste, and some other rules and regulations.

In the Vaishnava teachings, what is a fruitive activity? What actions are we human beings bound by then (apart from pure devotion)? Which other actions would fall under the definition of fruitive activity?

It would be really helpful if responses could be provided with references.